# SQL str() vs round() function

Tags: sql, rounding

While working with str() function I found that in some cases it rounds wrong while round() function works as expected. Please look at the example:

```
declare @v decimal(18,2) = 29.95
select str(@v, 18, 1)
--29.9
select round(@v, 1)
--30.00

set @v = 39.95
select str(@v, 18, 1)
--40.00
select round(@v, 1)
--40.00
```

Can anyone explain why it happens?

**EDIT1**:
I tested different workarounds with the following base code:

```
declare @v decimal(18,2) = 9.95
declare @r varchar(100)
declare @c int = 1000000
declare @ms int
declare @dt datetime2

set @dt = sysdatetime()

while @c > 0
begin
    set @r = --different roundings
    set @c = @c - 1
end

set @ms = DATEDIFF(ms, @dt, sysdatetime())
select @ms, @r
```

Option 1 (the original one, rounds wrongly in some cases):

```
str(@v, 18, 1)
```

Option 2 (slightly modified but rounds correctly):

```
str(round(@v, 1), 18, 1)
```

Option 3 (double conversion and rounding):

```
convert(varchar(20), convert(decimal(18,1), round(@v, 1)))
```

Option 4 (only double conversion):

```
convert(varchar(20), convert(decimal(18,1), @v))
```

**Results**:
Option 1 and 2 are roughly 2 times slower than the last two but the result is right-justified. The fastest is Option 4.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks! It's a really good article!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to [str()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) is a float so your decimal value is implicitly converted to a float(53) that is then converted to a string. So you see a floating point rounding error.

Do a slight modification to your query and you can see what is happening in the actual execution plan.

```
declare @v decimal(18,2) = 29.95
select top(1) str(@v, 18, 1)
```

```xml
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="str(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),[@v],0),(18),(1))">
```

Comment: How do I use the last line of code you wrote? And what would be the workaround so that I get correctly rounded varchar with best possible performance?

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev You should not use the last line. That is the answer to your "why it happens?".

Comment: I actually came to the same :), just thought maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev This is better `cast(cast(round(@v, 1) as decimal(18, 1)) as varchar(10))`. It avoids the float conversions completely,

Comment: Wouldn't this one be even better: convert(varchar, convert(decimal(18,1), @v))

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev Sure, convert to `decimal(18, 1)` does round the value. You should however make a habit of specifying a string length for your varchar value. Default in this case 30 but in other cases it is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of STR(); STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] ) clearly says that the number is a float_expression. Therefore whatever the number you give it will be first converted to a FLOAT(n) where default value of n = 53.

So

SELECT STR(4.65,5,1), SELECT STR(3.65,5,1)

Equal to:

SELECT STR(CAST(4.65 AS FLOAT(53)),5,1) , STR(CAST(3.65 AS FLOAT(53)),5,1)

If you specify n, say n = 4 it will give the answer you are expecting (ie; 4.7 and 3.7)

SELECT STR(CAST(4.65 AS FLOAT(4)),5,1) , STR(CAST(3.65 AS FLOAT(4)),5,1)
              --4.7,                     3.7

Comment: This still gives wrong result: declare @v decimal(18,2) = 9.95

SELECT STR(CAST(@v AS FLOAT(53)),5,1)
SELECT STR(CAST(@v AS FLOAT(4)),5,1)